# $\int x^3e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't find the solution to the following integral. I think a substitution doesn't work, since then the $dx$ which has to cancel out the $dx$ is in the exponent of $e.$ I can't think of a better method. Integration by parts also looks impossible to me, since $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ doesn't have an antiderivative. Does anyone have a suggestion?

$$\int x^3e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2} \, dx $$

I need this integral to solve the differential equation:
$y'+ xy=x^3$

Comment: "looks impossible to me" is quite a blank description. What exact problems did you face?

Comment: Consider the substitution $y=\frac 12x^2$.  Then $dy=xdx$, and $x^3e^{\frac 12x^2}dx=2ye^y$...

Comment: Notice that $(\frac12x^2)'=x$.

Comment: Use the [tabular method](https://www.rationalargumentator.com/index/blog/2014/07/tabular-method/) for integration by parts. Set

$$u=x^3, ~~dv=e^{x^2/2}$$

It appears that user has already posted the answer.

Comment: Actually, integration by parts show that $\int x^n e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$ is elementary for *odd* $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By parts

$$\int x^3e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2} \, dx=\int x^2\cdot xe^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=x^2\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}-\int 2x\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
u &= x^2/2 \\[8pt]
du & = x\,dx \\[8pt]
\int x^2 e^{x^2/2}\big( x\, dx\big) = {} & \int 2u e^u \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & 2\int u \,dv \\[8pt]
= {} & 2uv - 2\int v\, du\quad\text{(integration by parts)} \\[8pt]
& \text{etc.}
\end{align}
It is not true that $e^{x^2/2}$ doesn't have an antiderivative, but it doens't have an "elementary" antiderivative. This present function, however, can be handled by elementary methods, as above.